# How to check the value of wscript.arguments(0) without two if statements

Tags: wsh

I want to be able to check the value of the first passed argument to a windows script.  But I want to be able to do it in such a way that the script will not give a runtime error if there are no arguments passed.

This is only a matter of curiosity as I am able get my script working with two if statements, but I want to know if there's a way to do it with just one (like

```
monthly = false

if wscript.arguments.count > 0 then 

    if wscript.arguments(0) = "monthly" then

        monthly = true

    end if

end if
```

It would be neater if this could be done...

```
if wscript.arguments.count > 0 and wscript.arguments(0) = "Monthly" then

    monthly = true

end if
```

But that gives a subscript out of range error because the scripting engine is trying to check the value of an array item that doesn't exist.

I know I can do this type of check in PHP (`if(isset($_POST['somevariable'])) && $_POST['somevariable'] == 'somevalue'`)

Comment: Perhaps a dumb question but is this VBScript?

Comment: Yes,  I taggeed the question as wscript,  is that not vbscript by default?

Comment: I'm not fully qualified for this to be honest. But If(cond1 And cond2) **is** allowed in VBScript.

Comment: But if cond1 is false, the parser still checks cond2,  and in this particular case cond2 being checked with throw a subscript out of range error.  I know you can check more than one variable in an if statement.  But this particular case is different.  I've edited my question to make it slightly clearer.  the second value doesn't exist if the first value is false.

Comment: I guess what I'm really asking is what is a 'clean' way to check the value of an array item in a scenario where there might not be an array item in that position.

Comment: Got it, I knew I could help without knowing a thing about VBScript. Thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is you can't do it because VBScript has no short-circuit and operator.

Since this is out of curiousity, you can check these links :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

[VBScript conditional short-circuiting workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59599/vbscript-conditional-short-circuiting-workaround)

Comment: Thanks.  Thought as much.  But I'm a bit OCD so I like to explore 'clean' ways of doing things before settling on the slightly awkward ways that first occur to oneself when solving a coding problem.

Comment: The "select case" is marked as a replacement but it doesn't really look cleaner as a nested if so I don't really think it counts.

Answer (score 1):

If there is more than one test for the argument, you don't have to keep repeating the double if/then conditions.

Test once for the argument and put it in a variable. All other checks after that only need one if/then against the variable. Or use 'case' to select.

```
dim argument
if wscript.arguments.count > 0 then
    argument = wscript.arguments(0)
end if

if argument = "test1" then
  msgbox "test1"
end if

if argument = "test2" then
  msgbox "test2"
end if
```