# VBScript checks all OR conditions?

Tags: if-statement, vbscript

Perhaps I'm missing something, but it annoys me that VBScript seems to read all OR condtions. For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
If (oFS.FileExists(sFileLoc) = False) Or (sNewText <> oFS.OpenTextFile(sFileLoc).ReadAll) Then
```

Now I get an error that the file doesn't exist because of the second condition. I was hoping that if the file doesn't exist VBScript would skip immediately to the result, and if it *does*, it checks the second condition.

Am I right and is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [M. Harris already said in 2003](http://computer-programming-forum.com/59-vbscript/b2abfc61dd8fc42d.htm) and the docs for the logical operators (e.g. [Or](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6a4aywe%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)) state explicitly, VBScript does not short-circuit the evaluation of conditionals. You must use [nested Ifs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59606/603855) or a slightly fancy [Select Case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59693/603855)

Comment: Ah thanks! I couldn't find the answer but now I know that it's called short-circuiting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *inline* nested `IF`'s to achieve short-circuiting in VBScript. For example, you could rewrite your statement like this:

```
If oFS.FileExists(sFileLoc) Then If sNewText = oFS.OpenTextFile(sFileLoc).ReadAll Then
```

But your `Then` condition must be specified on the same line as this statement. So if you need to perform multiple operations as a result of this condition, you must separate the statements with a colon (`:`), which is the single-line statement separator in VBScript.

```
If oFS.FileExists(sFileLoc) Then If sNewText = oFS.OpenTextFile(sFileLoc).ReadAll Then x = 1 : y = 2
```

You could also just move your logic into a `Sub` or `Function` and make a call instead:

```
If oFS.FileExists(sFileLoc) Then If sNewText = oFS.OpenTextFile(sFileLoc).ReadAll Then DoStuff
```

Note, too, that if you need to specify an `Else` clause, it must be specified on this line as well.

```
If oFS.FileExists(sFileLoc) Then If sNewText = oFS.OpenTextFile(sFileLoc).ReadAll Then x = 1 Else x = 2
```

Comment: In how far is it required to put the nested if's into one line? And where is the End if? What the IF?

Comment: @TheBlastOne Lol. `End If` is not used in the single-line `If` construct. Only `If`, `Then`, and an optional `Else` are used. But you can still nest multiple `If`s, as shown above.